# React.js: Set sticky table-header cell width based on corresponding table-row cell width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Goal**

I'm wanting to create a table with a scrolling body and a sticky header. The table header cell widths need to match their corresponding body column widths.

It's in React, and the Table component contain two separate components (one for the header, and another for the rows in the body). The content of the components will be coming from an outside source, so I can't make any assumptions on the widths of anything. The body of the table will have a *lot* of rows, so the table header is going to need to be sticky and stay at the top.

**Problem**

While the widths of the columns in the table body are automatically set, the widths are not automatically set in the table head. The table header widths need to be automatically set based on the contents of the table.

You can see the issue and my test code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/y0jx5rp081

**Things to note**

- I'm open to using plugins or libraries if there's a good enough reason, but would rather not if possible
- I've already tried [react-sticky](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky), which doesn't support table format
- I've also tried [react-sticky-table](https://github.com/henrybuilt/react-sticky-table), which doesn't allow me to split the table into row components, which I need to do in order to help with more efficient rendering
- Once again, I need the widths to all be set automatically. The only solutions I have seen so far involve setting the width in the header manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the widths of your table cells by querying for them after rendering. To access a React component after rendering, we'll need to use a ref.

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.bodyRef = React.createRef()
}
```

Pass it as a prop to the table body.

```
<tbody
  ...
  ref={this.bodyRef}
>
```

Then you can access it after rendering in componentDidMount. If you remove, add or edit rows you may want to do it in componentDidUpdate as well (but be careful not to make an infinite loop).

```
componentDidMount() {
  const row = this.bodyRef.current.children[0].children; // Get the children of one <tr>
  // the path from this.bodyRef.current to the children you need may vary.
  const headerWidths = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i += 1) {
    headerWidths.push(row[i].getBoundingClientRect().width); // Get the rendered width of the element.
  }
  this.setState({
    headerWidths
  });
}
```

Then just use the width values in your state.

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.state = {
    ...
    headerWidths: []
  }
}
...
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <th style={{ width: this.state.headerWidths[index] }}>
      ...
    </th>
  )
}
```

Here's a working version of your handy example.

[image: Edit React Sticky Table-Header]

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful!

One thing I did notice is that for some reason, the widths aren't exact. If you check in the sandbox link you gave, the widths of the th and td elements aren't the same.

If I make a function that updates the widths again post-render, though, it seems to set the widths correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [react-sticky-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table) because I need an easy way to create a table with a freezable header and columns. You can't set the width of the cell using `width` but you can use `max-width` and `min-width` as a workaround, which is what I'm doing, to set the cell width. E.g.:

React/JS file:

```
<Cell className='sticky-table-cell'>
    ...
```

CSS file:

```
.sticky-table-cell{
      display: table-cell;
      min-width: 400px;
      max-width: 400px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```

`pre-wrap` makes sure that the text inside the cell breaks according to the available width.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I did some CSS workaround with position sticky and fixed height for container, to make first column and first header sticky. It works great as expected. Here is working codesandbox URL, hope it helps!

I used most popular [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table)  package out there!
https://codesandbox.io/embed/objective-frog-m4imr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package for this that I recommend that will save you time and energy. Check it out: [react-sticky-table-thead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table-thead) All you have to do is to wrap a component around your table like:

```
<StickyHeader>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Head</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</StickyHeader>
```